# Why do I get a opening file for writing error while installing Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my second time installing Android Studio. The first time I skipped this error, but I had problems whit the android device monitor so I had to uninstall it. Please can anyone help me with this. Here is the error I get:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed in C:\Program Files and it works perfectly. I just had to change the location

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running the setup as administrator?
Right click --> Run as administrator.